# Accessing e-mail attachments from Outlook web-addin on iOS

Tags: ios, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm currently developing an Outlook addin using the new web technologies.

What is not clear to me though: The method `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync` works differently on Desktop (Web) and iOS. On the Web, I get a token which decodes to the following:

```
{
  "nameid": "...",
  "ver": "Exchange.Callback.V1",
  "appctxsender": "https://.../core.html?button=ItemRead@0e7219f7-4c4d-47e7-b98a-7b9b9de02b80",
  "appctx": {
    "oid": "...",
    "puid": "10033FFF8670ACD2",
    "smtp": "...",
    "upn": "...",
    "scope": "ParentItemId:AAMkADQ2ZWI1NWUzLWFjNTgtNDhkNi05MTRlLTE0ZjkzYjhiZmIxYgBGAAAAAAAiCmOBDIX4TojSJs8PRerdBwCiXa8K4T4FToTXRfNegy16AAAAAAENAACiXa8K4T4FToTXRfNegy16AANl/D0YAAA="
  },
  "iss": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@0e7219f7-4c4d-47e7-b98a-7b9b9de02b80",
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/outlook.office365.com@0e7219f7-4c4d-47e7-b98a-7b9b9de02b80",
  "exp": 1491917568,
  "nbf": 1491917268
}
```

I can successfully call EWS to get the attachment of the e-mail (like so: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item.md)

On iOS however, the token I get looks like this - and it's also not possible to get the ewsUrl property.

```
{
  "oid": "...",
  "puid": "....",
  "smtp": "...",
  "upn": "..",
  "ver": "Exchange.Callback.V2",
  "appid": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
  "deploymentid": "https://outlook.office365.com/",
  "tid": "0e7219f7-4c4d-47e7-b98a-7b9b9de02b80",
  "acr": "1",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "scp": "Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite",
  "iss": "https://outlook.office365.com/",
  "aud": "https://outlook.office365.com",
  "exp": 1491918090,
  "nbf": 1491917190
}
```

This token does not work when used as a bearer token for EWS, so my guess is it would only work with the REST Api? Can Exchange.Callback.V2 in general only used with the REST Api? What is the criteria when to call EWS and when REST?

How do I support scenarios that are not Office365, when there is a on-premise Exchange 2016 server with no REST support?

Thanks
Tobias

Comment: Add-ins on Outlook mobile are only supported against Office 365, so you will never have a case in ios where you can't call REST.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!